# NgRx Store state for tabs

Tags: angular, angular6, ngrx

I am trying to implement something similar to the browser tabs in my application. Currently I'm creating a new key in the store for every opened tab and separately storing the current tab's id. Currently my store's state is similar to this:

```
{
  currentTab: 0,
  0: {
       url: 'http://google.com'
  }
  1: {
       url: 'http://twitter.com'
  }
}
```

Since I am pretty new to ngrx, I hope you can tell whether this is the right approach for this kind of things.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: We won't prefer saving UI state in the NGRX Store. You can store in Service and access it. NGRX store can be utilized for API Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually store your tabs with `@ngrx/entity`. UI state definitely belongs to the store, see [here](https://youtu.be/N_UQx8dPPkc?t=104).

Your reducer could look like

```js
import { createEntityAdapter, EntityState } from '@ngrx/entity';

import { TabsActions, TabsActionTypes } from '../actions';
import { Tab } from '../../models/tab';

export const adapter = createEntityAdapter<Tab>({
  selectId: tab => tab.id,
  sortComparer: (tabA, tabB) => tabA.id === tabB.id ? 0 : tabA.id > tabB.id ? 1 : -1
});

export interface State extends EntityState<Tab> {
  currentTab: number
}
export const initialState = adapter.getInitialState({
  currentTab: 0
});

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: TabsActions) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TabsActionTypes.Add:
      return adapter.add(action.payload, state);

    case TabsActionTypes.Close:
      return adapter.remove(action.payload, state);

    case TabsActionTypes.SwitchTab:
      return { ...state, currentTab: action.payload }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

With the actions defined as

```js
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Tab } from '../../models/tab';

export enum TabsActionTypes {
  Add = '[Tabs] Add',
  Close= '[Tabs] Close',
  SwitchTab = '[Tabs] Switch'
}

export class AddTab implements Action {
  readonly type = TabsActionTypes.Add;
  constructor(public payload: Tab) {}
}

// Define other actions (CloseTab, SwitchTab) in a similar way

export type TabsActions =
  AddTab |
  CloseTab |
  SwitchTab;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Starting to look into it now!